# How to view user badges Moodle

Tags: moodle, badge

I want to know where are stored in the database the badges that gain an user. This question becomes from the incident that I have with one user who has earned 5 badges and in his profile only appears 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the record of users earned badges in table "mdl_badge_issued".